# how to plotshape on ta.crossover conditionally

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm a complete newbie, please go easy on me!

I have a script that works, but I need to refine it.  The pertinent code is:

```
plotshape(series = ta.crossover(close,upper1), style=shape.xcross, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, display=display.pane)
plotshape(series = ta.crossunder(close,lower1), style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), size=size.tiny, display=display.pane)
```

As you might imagine, with the above code every time a bar closes either above upper1 or below lower1, a small cross is plotted above or below the respective bar.

What I would like it to do instead is first evaluate bar[2] to see if the condition is met on that bar and if it is to then move on to the next bar and restart the evaluation process from the beginning again.  If, however, the condition is not met on bar [2] then I would like the script to continue to the next line and evaluate bar[1] in the same manner as bar[2] such that if the condition is met on bar[1] then move to the next bar and restart the evaluation process from the beginning again.  If, however, the condition is still not met on bar[1] then I would like the script to continue to bar[0].  If the condition is met on bar[0] then plotshape as in my existing script.  If the condition is not met on bar[0] then restart the script from the beginning again on the next bar so on and so forth.

The net effect would be that the script would only plot 'x' either above or below a bar which has crossed over upper1 or crossed under lower1 provided that the same condition was not met on the previous two bars.

I hope that is clear.  My sense is that it really shouldn't be difficult to do, but as I have almost no experience with pine-script it is difficult for me to conceptualise in code, even though I have read the User Manual.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
var condition2Check = false
var condition1Check = false

if not condition2 // condition not met
    condition2Check := true

if condition2Check and not condition1 // condition2 not met before and now condition1 not met either
    condition1Check := true

condition0Check = false
if condition1Check and condition0 // condition2 not met before and condition1 not met either but then condition0 met --> then plotshape as in my existing script.
    condition0Check := true
    condition1Check := false
    condition2Check := false
else
    condition1Check := false // reset previous checks
    condition2Check := false // reset previous checks

coSeries = ta.crossover(close,upper1) // these must be called on each bar
cuSeries = ta.crossunder(close,lower1) // these must be called on each bar

plotshape(condition0Check ? coSeries : na, style=shape.xcross, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, display=display.pane)
plotshape(condition0Check ? cuSeries : na, style=shape.xcross, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), size=size.tiny, display=display.pane)
```

Basically that's one approach, however without knowing your conditions I cannot bring you further.
In this script you are checking your condition levels on the current bar (2,1,0 respectively) and storing the *real time* results in a `var` variable over to the next bar where you can check your next condition in regard to the previous.
Although depending on your situation you could also very well utilize the [history-referencing-operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html?highlight=historic#history-referencing-operator) on your series data to do a "look-back" on each bar checking the previous conditions backwards from the current bar. This is a very simple example of that:

```
...
if close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and condition0
    // plot condition met - Note: plot still needs to be called in the global scope
...
```

Not that this way you also need to make sure to add a check that controls when the last time was you plotted, because the condition above can be true on multiple consecutive bars and you may not want that.